# What is the right version of matplotlib for sympy 1.0?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I tried to use the plot module of Sympy(1.0) in Pycharm, but encounter errors like the one below. I guess it is caused by an version imcompatibility between matplotlib(2.0.2) and Sympy(1.0). Does anyone have a clue? Thanks in advance~

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leizh/PycharmProjects/Learn_python/Smoothness_Bilinear_Quadrilateral_Elmt.py", line 49, in <module>
    plot_parametric(cos(u),sin(u),(u,-5,5))
  File "/home/leizh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1415, in plot_parametric
    plots.show()
  File "/home/leizh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 184, in show
    self._backend = self.backend(self)
  File "/home/leizh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 1056, in __new__
    return MatplotlibBackend(parent)
  File "/home/leizh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 868, in __init__
    self.cm = self.matplotlib.cm
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cm'
```

The code is meant to calculate a mapping for a bilinear quadrilateral element.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import *

xi = Symbol("xi")
eta = Symbol("eta")

#Shape functions in reference element
def Ni(xi,eta,i):
    references_vertices = {1:[-1,-1],2:[1,-1],3:[1,1],4:[-1,1]}
    xiv = references_vertices[i][0]
    etav = references_vertices[i][1]
    return Rational(1,4)*(1+xiv*xi)*(1+etav*eta)

#Give a specific element in physical space with an angle >= 180 degree
physical_vertices = {1:[-1,-1],2:[1,-1],3:[1,1],4:[0,0]}

#Interpolation for (x,y) in terms of (xi,eta)
def mapping(xi,eta,vertices):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in vertices:
        xv = vertices[i][0]
        yv = vertices[i][1]
        x += Ni(xi,eta,i)*xv
        y += Ni(xi,eta,i)*yv
    return [x,y]

#mapping (xi, eta) -> (x, y)
xy = mapping(xi,eta,physical_vertices)
print("x and y")
print(factor(xy[0]))
print(factor(xy[1]))

#Jacobian
jac = []
jac.append([xy[0].diff(xi),xy[0].diff(eta)])
jac.append([xy[1].diff(xi),xy[1].diff(eta)])

print("Jacobian Matrix")
print(factor(jac))

#The determinant of Jacobian
det_jac = jac[0][0]*jac[1][1]-jac[0][1]*jac[1][0]
print(factor(det_jac))

#Plot
plot3d_parametric_surface(xy[0], xy[1], det_jac,(xi,-1,1),(eta,-1,1))
det_jac.subs([(xi,1),(eta,-1)])

#test
u = symbols('u')
plot(u**2,(u,-1,1))
plot_parametric(cos(u),sin(u),(u,-5,5))
```

Comment: did you see this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: Using a fresh virtual environment with python 3.5.3, matplotlib 2.0.2 and sympy 1.0 works smooth as ever. `sympy.plotting.plot_parametric(sympy.cos(u), sympy.sin(u), (u,-5,5))` renders a nice circle on my screen. Maybe you have encountered a bug in pycharm? I guess posting the relevant parts of your code that reproduce your error would help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just added the original code. By following the execution, the problem is located at the line of file sympy.plot.py: `self.matplotlib = import_module('matplotlib',
            __import__kwargs={'fromlist': ['pyplot', 'cm', 'collections']},
            min_module_version='1.1.0', catch=(RuntimeError,))`. It fails to import the module matplotlib. So I understand why it generates the error but still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Problem solved by installing the python3-tk package.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce your problem with matplotlib 2.0.2, sympy 1.0 and python 3.4.6. However using matplotlib 2.0.2, sympy 1.0 and python 3.5.3 works just fine. Note that I am using different computers, but fresh virtual environments every time. So there should be no other issues here. I suggest upgrading to python 3.5.x.

In the future please provide a "minimal" working example which reproduces your error, for example:

```
import sympy as sym

u = sym.symbols('u')

sym.plotting.plot(sym.sin(u), (u,-5,5))
```

**EDIT**: There was a difference between the 2 computers: one used the qt4agg backend (did not work), the other used tkagg (does work). So there seems to be a problem regarding which backend you use with sympy and matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is resoved on my computer by installing the package python3-tk. You are right with the backend that works with matplotlib. So it's not a problem about compatibility between Sympy and Matplotlib. Maybe i need to change the question's title...